# Marshalling output pointers during P/Invoke calls from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, pointers, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C library with this function that returns 4 output parameters:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) demofun(double a[], double b[], double* output1, double* output2, double res[], double* output3)
```

And I wrote a C# wrapper to call the function:

```
namespace cwrapper
{
    public sealed class CWRAPPER
    {    
        private CWRAPPER() {}

        public static void demofun(double[] a, double[] b, double output1,
                            double output2, double[] res, double output3)
        {   // INPUTS: double[] a, double[] b
            // OUTPUTS: double[] res, double output1, double output2
            // Arrays a, b and res have the same length
            // Debug.Assert(a.length == b.length)

            int length = a.Length;
            CWRAPPERNative.demofun(a, b, length, ref output1, ref output2,
                         res, ref output3);
        }
    }

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal sealed class CWRAPPERNative
    {
        private CWRAPPERNative() {}

        [DllImport("my_cwrapper.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
             ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=false)]
        internal static extern void demofun([In] double[] a, [In] double[] b,
                             int length, ref double output1, ref double output2,
                             [Out] double[] res, ref double output3);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I call the `CWRAPPERNative.demofun` method. However, when I call the `CWRAPPER.demofun` method, only the `double[] res` is passed through correctly. The output parameters `output1`, `output2` and `output3` are unchanged after the call.

```
// ...
// Initializing arrays A and B above here

double[] res = new double[A.Length];
double output1 = 0, output2 = 0, output3 = 0;

// Works partially: output1 to 3 unchanged
CWRAPPER.demofun(A, B, output1, output2, res, output3);

// Works correctly: all outputs are changed
CWRAPPERNative.demofun(A, B, A.Length, ref output1, ref output2, res, ref output3);
```

I'm guessing that I'm marshalling the pointer arguments wrongly, but I cannot figure out the fix. Anyone knows a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to pass the values by reference inside of demofun:

```
public static void demofun(double[] a, double[] b, ref double output1,
   ref double output2, double[] res, ref double output3)
```

The values is changing inside of the method, but not being modified to the original caller.

Comment: That solves the problem! But now it seems like an inconvenience to go through that just to remove the length argument as compared to `CWRAPPERNative.demofun`. Maybe I should just pass the outputs through a struct so it's cleaner?

CWRAPPER.demofun also takes roughly 12.5% more time than CWRAPPERNative.demofun averaged over 10000 iterations. This seems like a trivial concern since we are talking about microseconds, but this is bearing in mind that I'm interoping with C to take advantage of AVX/SSE intrinsics. How would you optimize this? I'll like to hear what you think. Thanks aplenty!

Answer (score 0):

All `double` parameters to `CWRAPPER.demofun` are non-volatile, i.e. the values cannot be changed by the function. To fix this you need a change like this:

```
public static void demofun(double[] a, double[] b,
  out double output1, out double output2, double[] res, out double output3)
```

There's another problem though. The C function's 5th parameter `double res[]` is an input parameter but your P/Invoke declaration has `[Out] double[] res` (an output parameter).  I'd rewrite the P/Invoke declaration like this:

```
[DllImport("my_cwrapper.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
  ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=false)]
static extern void demofun([In] double[] a, [In] double[] b, [In] int length,
  [Out] double output1, [Out] double output2, [In] double[] res, [Out] double output3);
```

Example method implementation with `out` parameter; `OutOutTester` shows that a method with `out` parameters need not assign their values directly:

```
public static void OutTester(out int a)
{
    a = 1;
}

public static void OutOutTester(out int a, out int b)
{
    OutTester(out a);
    b = 1;
}
```

Comment: I can't compile using `out` in the calling method because the out parameters must be assigned before the control leaves the method. I felt the logical way to proceed was to use `out` in the calling method and assign temporary variables e.g. `double temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0, temp3 = 0;` inside of `demofun`, pass the temporary variables to `CWRAPPERNative.demofun`, then assign `output1 = temp1;` etc. But for some reason, the outputs return as 0's.

Comment: The outputs return as 0's from `CWRAPPER.demofun` because those parameters are _non-volatile_. But those parameters in `CWRAPPERNative.demofun` return as the expected values because they are volatile, due to the `ref` keyword. You can achieve the same thing by replacing `ref` by `out` which is better for code security. See my updated answer for an example.